Can I use bootstrapping for small sample sizes to satisfy the power analysis requirements?
I have 15 participants who conducted a task in Condition A and 15 participants who conducted the task in Condition B. To increase the validity of the data, each participant repeated the task 20 times. To my understanding, within an ANOVA, this data is still considered only as 15 data points per condition because, for each participant, the 20 repetitions are reduced to one average value. So my understanding is that the ANOVA does not take into account that I had a total of 2×300 measurements, and I may as well have only measured once per participant.
The issue: Although the data seem consistently smaller in Condition A than in Condition B, a power analysis suggests that I require a sample size ten times larger. I do not have the possibility to repeat the study anymore and definitely not with the required sample size.
The repeated measures within the participants show that the repetitions are independent from each other (e.g., no learning effect, etc.). That means, for me, that in fact I have more like 300 data points in each condition that just the 15 averaged ones. If I compare the 300 data points in the two conditions against each other, without averaging the measurements, the statistics work out. Not though with a sample size of 15.
Questions:

Is there a possibility to use the repeated measures to bootstrap the data with the ultimate goal to satisfy the required sample size?

If so, which bootstrapping procedure would you recommend?

Any other suggestions that wouldn't require for me to redo the entire experiment?



This sounds like a textbook example of repeated-measures ANOVA, does it not? I don’t see the need for any kind of bootstrap. Just fit the ANOVA while accounting for the repeated measures. Do you see something more complicated?

"a power analysis suggests, that I require a sample size ten times larger" What does that mean exactly? What sort of power are you calculating here, for which effect size (the observed effect size, or the effect size that would be relevant to you)? I am asking because maybe you interpret an insignificant result as useless (a failed experiment) and you conclude 'I simply need more power to make what I measured significant'. An insignificant result can also be interpreted as informative as it let's you know that certain large effect sizes are unlikely. Compute the confidence interval.


This is precisely why you do your power analysis and sample size calculation before you run the experiment.
Yes, the result may be that you do not have the resources to run an adequately powered experiment. But then you should not run an inadequately powered experiment "because you don't have the resources", because that way you waste the resources you do invest. If your power analysis indicates issues, you either acquire more resources or reallocate those you have or modify your experiment. Or you abandon this experiment and invest your resources elsewhere.
R. A. Fisher:

To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of.


You write:

The repeated measures within the participants show that the repetitions are independent from each other (e.g., no learning effect etc.)

This is fallacious. Learning effects are by far not the only dependence there is. Some participants may simply be better or worse at the task overall, without necessarily learning during the task. Their measurements would still be dependent. So no, you can't just treat them as independent.

What you are looking for are (linear) mixed effects models, also known as repeated effects models, which indeed do model precisely the dependence structure you probably have, namely repeated measurements within one unit. Of course you should not simply take the average measurement within each participant and feed this into an ANOVA, this loses a lot of information.

Finally:

Is there a possibility to use the repeated measures to bootstrap the data with the ultimate goal to satisfy the required sample size?

This is not how the bootstrap works. It does not simulate a sample size that does not exist. (Otherwise, why would anyone ever collect a large sample if they could simply collect a small sample and "bootstrap" it "to the right size"?) The bootstrap is a tool to assess the variability of parameter estimates using fewer distributional assumptions than "classical" theory, with the sample and sample size you actually have.


I recommend that you consult with a statistician at your institution, who you can explain your experiment to in more detail. Be prepared to offer them authorship, which may be well deserved if they make serious contributions to the analysis. At the very least, read up on and apply mixed effects models, and at this point, do not look to the bootstrap. Going forward, involve the statistician already at the planning stage of your experiments.

Thank you, Stephan.  You are right in so many points, but now I need to see how I sort it out with what I have. I will try to look into the recommendations of Shawn.

Actually, if the data is balanced (20 data points for each participant), there's no loss of information about the fixed condition effect: lm(y.bar ~ condition) should give the same result as lmer(y ~ condition + (1 | participant)). Though it's better to use mixed models; they work in the balanced and the unbalanced situation.

What Stephan has said here already reflects what I would have said (+1). My answer is more about what could possibly be done now rather than what should have been done already (which I recognize here may be too late in your case).
 You note that the subjects are in different conditions, but I assume they all share the same stimuli based off your description. If that is the case, than rather than using a repeated measures ANOVA, I would recommend instead using a crossed random effects linear mixed model (as Stephan alluded to some degree already), which will multiply the stimuli x subject observations by treating both stimuli and subjects as random effects. So if there are 300 stimuli used across 15 people, this would net $n = 4500$ observations, as it would estimate $300$ observations within each subject and $15$ observations within each stimulus/tasks (hence, "crossed").
Scratch this suggestion. The wording of your question originally led me to believe that you had multiple tasks (namely because of the latter part of the post), but commentary from dipetkov led me to re-read the beginning of your question and it seems you just have one task in each condition. Therefore, my previous suggestion above wouldn't be helpful. You could still model the by-subject random effect here in a mixed model, but as he says, the differences between a repeated measures ANOVA and LMM may not be that extreme if the data is balanced.
Repeated measures are good at boosting the power of an already tiny sample size, but they have their limits (particularly if you don't have the convenience of fully crossed effects like I mention above). One alternative is to use a Bayesian ANOVA instead (here just a linear mixed model with Bayesian estimation methods), replacing the assumed "priors" of a frequentist model with informative priors from previous research. If you know for example that these groups have a certain positive mean difference over the other, with very little variation, then you can add that prior directly into the Bayesian version of the model. This would ensure that, while the sample is limited, it is "informed" by past research, which is to say that it will be less dominated by sample-specific idiosyncrasies. These sorts of Bayesian ANOVAs with random effects can be straightforwardly estimated in the brms package in R (see package info here). I read this book last year about small sample size analysis, which gives some treatment on the conceptual ideas behind Bayes in these situations.

You make very good points (as always!). Another reason IMO to ideally talk to a statistician in more depth and go through the details with them, even at this stage... (and I do realize that this may be unrealistic).

What stimulii? The OP makes a claim that "the (within-participant) repetitions are independent from each other", so seems to suggest it's okay to treat the data as if there were 300 (= 15 * 20) participants per condition.

Moreover, this experiment is balanced, so wouldn't we expect to see little difference between the repeated measures anova and the mixed model as far as the difference between the two conditions -- with the condition effect fixed in both analyses?

Many thanks, Shawn, that's very kind of you. Apologies in advance if I say anything stupid. I would like to look into the "crossed random effects linear mixed model" that you mention. Is that the same as a two-way ANOVA that uses "random effects" as model? Are we talking here about this one: https://www.statskingdom.com/two-way-anova-calculator.html where i chose in the model drop-down "random effects"?
Any recommendation how I justify using using "random effects" instead of "repeated measures"?

You justify random effects (REs) designs because the obs. are not independent (repeated measures are often used as REs). I'm not sure what you or @dipetkov mean here (maybe both of you can clarify), but observations of one subject will be more similar to each other than observations of another subject, same goes for tasks. I'm not sure what you mean by there not being a learning effect or the observations being independent but perhaps you can explain. Mixed models also have the benefit of modeling by-subject / by-task variance (e.g. one task having more inconsistent scoring than another).

For the simple data (completely balanced) & model (one fixed effect) the OP seems to describe, the repeated measures anova and the mixed model should produce very similar inference for the fixed effect. The mixed effects will have an advantage if there are different number of observations from participants as it will pool the data accordingly. I tried it on some simulated data with lmer(y ~ condition + (1 | subject), data = dat) and aov(y ~ condition + Error(subject), data = dat).

As far as I can see in this experiment there was one task, under two conditions, with a between-participant design. If that's the case it's hard to see what the OP can do differently. The only thing I can see if there happens to be some covariate that can explain some of the differences in task performance between participants.

Ahh now that I'm re-reading this, I see that detail more clearly now. I have amended my answer and thanks for bringing this up @dipetkov. You are indeed correct on this point.

Many thanks for your thoughts. So, there was in fact one task, under two conditions, with a between-participant design. The 2 x 15 participants did the task 20 times. However, the  20 task repetitions were not exactly the same, as there were small parameter changes that the participant was confronted with (the given speed and direction within the task varied across the repetitions in a controlled manner).  Does this allow me to define the repetitions as a "random factor" instead of "repeated measures"?

The outcome of my statistics changes whether I use linear mixed-effects model (p = 0.01) or whether I use a repeated measures ANOVA (p = 0.15). The degrees of freedom for first one is (1, 598) and for the latter one (1, 38).
I have seen several sources now, where a mixed-effects model has been used instead of a repeated-measures model. I am just not sure, if I can use the first one and how do I justify it toward the reviewers.

Both LMMs and repeated measures ANOVA here are using repeated measures. Both can also be technically used for the same problem, but linear mixed models tend to be more flexible. The p-value derived from a linear mixed model by default uses Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom and the consequent p-value obtained. Perhaps you can share the code you used for fitting the model by writing a new question about that specific problem (linking it to this one), otherwise it is difficult to say much more about the differences in the models.

Not only do I agree with Stephen and the quote from R. A. Fisher that he gave, I even wrote a poem about it.
Dissertation Blues by Peter Flom
I’ve designed a great experiment
And collected all my data.
I’ve no idea what it all means —
I’ll get to that stuff later.

I’ve forgotten all the stats I learned
(And I never learned that much)
I needed it to pass my comps
But since then I’ve lost touch.

I’ll do another lit review
And find another theory
But when it’s time to analyze
Everything goes bleary.

So I hired a consultant
To tell me what I’d got.
He looked at three years of my life
And answered “not a lot.”

“There is no dissertation here
"There aren’t any theses.
"Basically what you have got
"Is a great big pile of feces.”

“You should have called me years ago
"Now get this through your head:
"You’ve hired a physician
"But the patient is quite dead”.

But I can make some suggestions in addition to those given by Shawn.
First, you can still present your results. Having low power does not invalidate any analysis, it simply means that your estimates won't be that good and that it is not likely that you will get statistically significant results. But you can still present them and then add "further research is needed". (I've never seen a paper end with "no further research is needed"!). Or "while these results are suggestive, they need to be repeated with a larger sample."
Second, you can make graphs that show what is going on.

Peter, you wrote a poem! (+1) only for that!

I wrote it a long time ago.

You should continue doing that, Peter. Merry Christmas.

Yes, Peter, I thought of it. However, when a sample size is too small and I don't get statistically significant results, I won't be able to get it published. I guess that most reviewers will reject it. So, I need to see what I will get out of the data that I have. And I hope that I can still get something out of the total of 300 measurements across 15 participants in each condition.
